# Import error while using Python on VS Code

Tags: jupyter

I need some help regarding an 'incompatible architecture' between 'x86_64' and 'arm64', because of which I can't run my Python code on the VS Code.
I have attached the error message below.

> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call
> last)
>
> ~/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/**init**.py
> in module
> 22 try:
> ---> 23     from . import multiarray
> 24 except ImportError as exc:
>
> ~/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py
> in 
> 9 import functools
> ---> 10 from . import overrides
> 11 from . import _multiarray_umath
>
> ~/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py
> in 
> 5
> ----> 6 from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
> 7     add_docstring, implement_array_function, _get_implementing_args)
>
> ImportError:
> dlopen(/Users/julieta/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-39-darwin.so,
> 0x0002): tried:
> '/Users/julieta/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-39-darwin.so'
> (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need
> 'arm64')),
> '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/julieta/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-39-darwin.so'
> (no such file),
> '/Users/julieta/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-39-darwin.so'
> (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need
> 'arm64'))
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

I'm using a Mac mini with M1 chip, my OS is Ventura 13.2, I am using Visual Studio Code.app with version of [1.75.1], and the app was downloaded from from the [Visual Studio Code website](https://code.visualstudio.com/download).

Can anybody direct what could be the problem and how to overcome it?

Comment: Please don't post error messages as screen shots. It prevents proper indexing by search engines and renders screen readers useless. Use plain text with Wiki markup instead.

Comment: From the error message, I'd guess you've installed the x86_64 version on an Apple Silicon based Mac. Please [edit] your question and add more information about your system (Hardware, operating system VS Code version, installation procedure etc.)

Comment: @FrankSchmitt I have edited the question's text as much as I could (I'm sorry, I don't know how to use Wiki markup for now). As for the additional information, I am using Mac mini with M1 chip, my OS is Ventura 13.2, I am using Visual Studio Code.app with version of [1.75.1], and the app was downloaded from from this website [link] (https://code.visualstudio.com/download). I would like to add that while checking when I downloaded the app, the date was showing Feb 9, 2023. However, I had been using the same app from early last year.

Comment: No worries, I've re-formatted it and included the info from your comment.